# Facebook SDK version 4.28.0, App Invites is deprecated

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-invite-friends

**Facebook SDK version 4.28.0, some products will sunset**

> With the release of the Facebook SDK version 4.28.0, App Invites is
>   deprecated. It will be supported until February 5, 2018.

Facebook has removed AppInvitation from latest SDK. Does anyone know alternative to implement AppInvite or is there any way to invite `Facebook` friends from iOS application. If we integrate Facebook game request and try to pull friend list into the app and then send game request instead of app invite will that be a feasible solution? Are user able to install App from `App store` and `Play store` stores?

**It's not duplicate because this question is about iOS and your duplicate post is for Android so the solution won't be the same

Comment: It's not duplicate because this question is about iOS and your duplicate post is for Android so the solution won't be the same